# Can one class library project be compiled as .net standard and .net framework?

Tags: .net, .net-standard

I have a project that is currently compiled for .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5. I also have a different project that uses .Net Core 2.0.

There is code that is shared between them, it would be very helpful if I could create a .Net Standard 2.0 class library, but we still need to support .Net Framework 4.0.

Is there any way to compile the class library for both .Net Framework 4.0 and as a .Net Standard 2.0 class library (Assuming the class library doesn't use any dependencies that aren't supported by both)?

Answer (score 1):

In short:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net40;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

When you build, this will create each target separately. If you are using automatic nupkg generation (`<GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>`), the nupkg will contain all targets. If you need to configure things differently for each, you can test the `TargetFramework` variable in the build file, which will be applied individually per target. This can be used to add different references or other configuration options, for example:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net20'">
    <FeatureServiceModel>false</FeatureServiceModel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.3'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);COREFX</DefineConstants>
    <ImportLibs>core</ImportLibs>
    <FeatureServiceModel>false</FeatureServiceModel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```